# Firefox or similar application for tab browsing UTF-16

Tags: xml, utf-16

Im working with set of UTF-16 encorded xml files. 
Example files are here
http://tipitaka.org/sinh/cscd/

What I wanted to do is to search a keyword from all these files and open all files with the given keyword.

The script Im using is this.

```
#!/bin/sh
grep $1 *.xml | sed 's/ *:.*//' | uniq > list.dat

while read line; do
    gedit "$line"
done < list.dat
```

So far I have used;

1. Firefox - Displays the file fine ( firefox -new-tab option) but doesn't open in tabs correctly . Once I close the current tab only the second tab pops up
2. chrome - Pops the tabs as expected but doesn't display XML file
3. gedit- pops and shows the content in tabs but doesn't format the text as a browser.

Is there any application or a fix to open list of xml files with all the formatting in tab form ?

secondly is there a way to highlight this search text once the tab is opened.

Thanks much.

Comment: what do you want to do with it afterwards? personally, I'd probably use commandline tools like `grep` and `xmllint`...

Comment: Hi, What I want to do is to open all the documents containing the search word in tabs in any application for reading. And highlighting is a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might show one or two of the techniques you need.

```
import requests
import webbrowser

URLtemplate = 'http://tipitaka.org/sinh/cscd/abh02m.mul%s.xml'

unencodedWord = 'වත්‌ථු'
word = bytearray(unencodedWord.encode('utf-16be'))

for k in range(0,18):
    URL = URLtemplate % k
    r = requests.get(URL)
    print ( r. apparent_encoding, end = '' )
    if r. apparent_encoding != 'UTF-16BE':
        print ( "can't process" )
        continue
    else:
        print ()
    if r.content.find(word) > -1:
        webbrowser.open(URL)
        input ('tap enter when ready for next page (if any):')
```